# nameservers update differently with openconnect and openconnect-gnome in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dns, vpn, ubuntu-18.04, networkmanager, openconnect

This seems to be a new issue with `network-manager-openconect-gnome` in Ubuntu 18.04+

I install `sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect-gnome` to get gnome integration with opeconnect and *Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN (openconnect)*

As an aside (which may *actually* be relevant) I do this to get `*.local` addresses to resolve:

- `sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` [as per systemd docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html)
- Move `dns` before `mdns4_minimal` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

If I connect to the VPN with openconnect through the gnome network manager, VPN addresses (sites for work) do not resolve. Regular sites continue to work as expected.

If I connect to the VPN with openconnect on the command line with `sudo openconnect vpn.mycompany.com`, VPN addresses (sites for work) **do** resolve. Regular sites continue to work as expected.

I thought I would check to see if there were any differences between `/etc/resolv.conf` with each of these VPN connection methods and sure enough, there is one:

**openconnect on the command line** (working):

```
#@VPNC_GENERATED@ -- this file is generated by vpnc
# and will be overwritten by vpnc
# as long as the above mark is intact
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 10.10.10.10
nameserver 10.10.10.11
search broadband mycompany.com
```

**openconnect gnome integration** (not working):

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 10.10.10.10
nameserver 10.10.10.11
search broadband mycompany.com
```

If I remove (or comment out) the nameserver `192.168.1.1`, which is the difference in content between the working and not working files... everything works as expected. I can resolve addresses within the company and regular sites work as expected.

This does not happen with Fedora. Everything works out of the box. I'm not sure why the `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` package works differently or if there's a way I can make it work without either

- Editing the file by hand.
- Using the `openconnect` tool from the command line and keeping a terminal open running that command.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you solve it?